# Low conversion quality using ffmpeg to merge audio and video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, mp4, wav

This is what I'm using to merge audio and video in my C# Win From Application and it works fine, but the video bit rate is very low. I'd like to keep the bit rate as it was for the original video, how can I do that?

I searched for solutions and found some things and tried experimenting with `-crf`and `-vb` but it just stopped working, I'm sure I put it in the wrong place.

```
"/c ffmpeg -i D:\\Me\\Test\\Cinematic_Romance.mp4 -i D:\\Me\\Test\\True_Romance_#_195.wav -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -shortest D:\\Me\\Test\\Cinematic_Romance_(with_audio).mp4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

`ffmpeg -i D:\\Me\\Test\\Cinematic_Romance.mp4 -i D:\\Me\\Test\\True_Romance_#_195.wav -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -shortest D:\\Me\\Test\\Cinematic_Romance_(with_audio).mp4`

This will copy the first input's video without recompressing it.